# R poly what family of polynomials?

Tags: r, polynomial

The R `poly` function documentation says that it gives orthogonal polynomials, but it's not clear *what* orthogonal polynomials it gives.  Are they [Legendre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials)?  Are they [Chebyshev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials)?  What family of orthogonal polynomials does R `poly` use?

Comment: They are determined by the *data,* not some mere mathematical basis.

Comment: @whuber I take it that you are suggesting with your dupe link that benjaminChristofferson's answer is the procedure R's `poly` uses?